# Designing a website with image tiles

Tags: jquery, image

I'm trying to implement a design where, besides the `nav`, a section of images fill up the page, like tiles. But the images are album covers, so they are usually (with exceptions) equal in terms of width and height.

The difficult part about this is that I'm trying to do this in full screen (width-wise), so that the section where the images are lined up adjust to the user's PC screen size. At the moment, the HTML looks like this:

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <section id="cont">
        <section class="row1">
            <div>
                <img src="./img/album/#.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="./img/album/#.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="./img/album/#.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="./img/album/#.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="./img/album/#.jpg" />
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

So, each `div` is given `width: 20%`, making one section spread across the whole page with 5 `div`s. The images are `width: 100%`, so that they fill out each `div` completely. Then, I add another `section` to make the second row, and so on.

My question is, how should I implement this correctly, and with least coding (for the user experience). I've tried using jQuery Masonry, but it's a little bit different from what I want. Any suggestions?

---

*Added later

I also want to add that some of these tiles will include text, but the size of div may differ, i.e. same with as the images, but longer in length. Also, I want to be able to set a height to the section#cont via JS or something similar, so that I can place a footer below it.

This is the current design. I want to make it so that say, the farthest album cover can be replaced with a colored, different sized div containing text, but the divs that follow will fit in tightly.

[img]http://automaton-hacks.tumblr.com/image/44124223193

Answer (score 0):

Try using an HTML table, I suppose?

Comment: I haven't really though of using a table for this. Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a grid system. I recommend http://960.gs.

You can also try http://unsemantic.com/ which works with percentages instead of fixed number of columns.

These work by dividing the total page into equal columns. You can select how many columns you want to use depending on the size of the window with css media queries. Thus by doing this you can set how many imgs are displayed per row automatically.

It does all this without any of those table shmables. Look into it, you just might like it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried both, but it seems they both require me to set my width at 960. Do you have any recommendations for allowing me to have a section of the page where width-wise it's 100%, but height depends on the width of each image? I'm having problems putting footers below the grids in my current HTML.

Comment: The grid will work just fine for that. When you use media queries you can set the width to whatever you want 960 is just a name not a recommendation. The div with the footer would come after #wrapper. Since you would be using media queries, the amount of images displayed per row is relative. Thus the height is also relative since you can't fit them all on one row. The footer would be moved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this: [**in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uUZtr/)

### css:

```
section{
    width:100%; 
    clear:both;
}

div{
   width:20%; 
   float:left; 
   background:#e1e1e1;
}

img{
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}
```

### html:

```
<section class="row1">
   <div>
      <img src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jeans-pocket-social-media-icon-set/128/facebook.png" />
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jeans-pocket-social-media-icon-set/128/facebook.png" />
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jeans-pocket-social-media-icon-set/128/facebook.png" />
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jeans-pocket-social-media-icon-set/128/facebook.png" />
      <p>This is content for img. This is content for img. This is content for img. This is content for img. This is content for img. This is content for img. </p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jeans-pocket-social-media-icon-set/128/facebook.png" />
   </div>
</section>
```